# The correct way to fade in/out different blocks in the same space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fade

I have a collection of buttons arranged horizontally across the screen and below those buttons is a space where I want different kinds of content to appear. For example, if I have a button named "biography" and I click on it, I would like a block containing  biography text to fade in. If I then click on "pictures", the biography block should fade out and the pictures block should fade in.

The current solution that I have (and I know it's wrong) is as follows. Below my buttons I have a table with rows corresponding to the different blocks that I want to display, like this:

```
+---------------------+
|                     |
|      biography      |
|                     |
+---------------------+
|                     |
|      pictures       |
|         ...         |
```

I set them all to `display: none` in my stylesheet and then when a button is clicked, I fade out all of the rows and fade in the one that I want displayed. It isn't clean and it probably isn't the best way to do things.

Here's the jQuery code that I have:

```
var blocks = [
     "projects-fade",
     "blog-fade",
     "online-fade",
     "resume-fade"
]

$("#projects").click( function()
{
    // Fade out all blocks
    $.each(blocks, function()
    {
       $("#" + this).fadeOut(100);
    })
    // Fade in the correct block
    $("#projects-fade").fadeIn(300);
});
// the code above is repeated for each button
```

In the code `#projects` is a button named "projects", and `blocks` is an array containing the ID's of all the text containers that appear in the space below the buttons. As you can see in the code, when `#projects` is clicked, all the blocks fades out (in the event one is open and taking up space) and then it fades in the relevant block (in this case `#projects-fade`).

How can I achieve this in a better way?

Comment: The first step would be to post some code.

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML and Javascript/jQuery in your question.  Can't really comment/improve upon what you have without seeing what you have.

Comment: @jfriend00 I added the jquery I have up to now

Comment: If my understanding of your question is correct, you're looking for an accordion. For instance, jQuery UI has one here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you don't have all your buttons/links inside a container already, then put them inside a `div` and give it the ID `menu`. Then do the same with your "blocks", but give that container the ID `blocks`. When that's done, change your JQuery code to this:

```
$("#menu a").click(function()
{
    // Assuming the buttons have the same id's as the blocks, minus "-fade"
    var blockID = $(this).attr("id") + "-fade";

    // Fade out the active block
    $("#blocks .active-block").fadeOut(300, function()
    {
        $(this).removeClass("active-block");

        // Fade in the new block
        $("#" + blockID).addClass("active-block");
        $("#" + blockID).fadeIn(600);
    });        
});
```

It's similar to your current code, but it's pretty much all you can do if you don't want to use AJAX.

Comment: I'm not sure if AJAX is what I'm looking for. The text blocks are just a couple links and some text (max 5 lines), so its easily embeddable in the current page. Would AJAX still apply?

Comment: @MaxMackie - Apparently misunderstood your question. Edited my answer

Comment: @MaxMackie - Thanks for the accept, but could you please also upvote my answer :)